# PHP 5.7 - call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$classe = $_POST['classe'];
$metodo = $_POST['metodo'];
$args = $_POST['args'];

call_user_func_array(array($classe, $metodo), $args);
```

Before, when I was with PHP 5.3, everything was OK.
Now, with PHP 5.7 I get this error.

How should I use the function now?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `PHP 5.7`? Where are you from?

Comment: Did you mean PHP 7.0?

Comment: It seems you've meant php 7, that's at first. And about the error - if your method `$metodo` is static - tell that to php, at the place where your method is created `static function ... `

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. `array($classe, $metodo)` In this syntax, `$classe` is supposed to be an instance of an object. But you're passing it a string provided by a user

Comment: I'm sorry! I meant PHP 7.

Comment: @Machavity let's say I had done this way: `$classe = 'Class'; $metodo='Method';`. It would return the same error. That's just an example.

Comment: @Giu171 Check out the duplicate. It explains how to use it properly

Comment: Thanks @Machavity and sorry for the duplicated question. It worked.

Comment: @Giu171 Nothing to be sorry about. No shame in having a question closed as a dupe. Downvotes are worse.